# Code block not being executed after fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs

I'm trying to read an uploaded `.csv` file and store it in an array for bulk insertion of data to my database, I'm using `csv-parser` package and `fs` for file stream.

```
router.post('/fileupload', function(request, response, next){
var bulk_emp_data = [];
if(request.files){
  var sampleFile = request.files.filename;
  console.log(sampleFile.name);
  sampleFile.mv('C:\\Users\\QPS-AUDRICK\\Desktop\\QBOS Timekeeping\\qbos\\public\\temp\\'+sampleFile.name, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log('Error moving ' + err);
    }else{
      fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\QPS-AUDRICK\\Desktop\\QBOS Timekeeping\\qbos\\public\\temp\\'+sampleFile.name)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log(results);
          bulk_emp_data = results;
          console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
          console.log(bulk_emp_data.length);
        });
        console.log('sample output');
    }
  });
}

var data = {
    success: 1,
    msg: 'Successfully parsed the sample file.',
    data: bulk_emp_data.length
};

response.json(data);
});
```

After reading the file thru `fs.createReadStream`, it seems that my `console.log` is not being executed. Here are the last 2 lines of the terminal.

```
CSV file successfully processed
63
```

Also, the `bulk_emp_data` variable seemed to be emptied. Here is the result for the `response`

```
{"success":1,"msg":"Successfully parsed the sample file.","data":0}
```

Notice that the last line on the terminal is 63 when it should be the `console.log()` and on the `response` the `bulk_emp_data.length` is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some execution order misconceptions.

> After reading the file thru fs.createReadStream, it seems that my console.log is not being executed.

Actually the `console.log` is executed instantly after starting the stream with `fs.createReadStream()`. The read stream is started, the two `on()` are executed only when the events `data` or `end` are fired by the stream itself, so you shuold see the `'sample output'` before any `'CSV file successfully processed'`.

Also the `bulk_emp_data.length` is printed before the streams ends, so it's zero (theoretically it can be some value but pratically never the real one).

Adding some comment on you're code to be more clear:

```
router.post('/fileupload', function (request, response, next) {
  var bulk_emp_data = [];
  if (request.files) {
    var sampleFile = request.files.filename;
    console.log(sampleFile.name);

    // sync operation - the execution "waits" here
    sampleFile.mv('C:\\Users\\QPS-AUDRICK\\Desktop\\QBOS Timekeeping\\qbos\\public\\temp\\' + sampleFile.name, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error moving ' + err);
      } else {

        // async operation
        // start a stream and attach some event listener
        fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\QPS-AUDRICK\\Desktop\\QBOS Timekeeping\\qbos\\public\\temp\\' + sampleFile.name)
          .pipe(csv())
          // executed when the stream fires the 'data' event
          .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
          // executed when the stream fires the 'end' event
          .on('end', () => {
            console.log(results);
            bulk_emp_data = results;
            console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
            console.log(bulk_emp_data.length);
          });

        // executed after starting the stream (and pratically before any event that the stream can fire)
        console.log('sample output');
      }
    });
  }

  // executed after "console.log('sample output')"  (and pratically before any event that the stream can fire)
  var data = {
    success: 1,
    msg: 'Successfully parsed the sample file.',
    data: bulk_emp_data.length
  };

  // executed pratically before any event that the stream can fire
  response.json(data);
});
```

Recap of execution order:

1. sampleFile.mv()
2. fs.createReadStream()
3. console.log('sample output')
4. var data = { ... }
5. response.json(data)
6. fs.createReadStream().on('data') X times
7. fs.createReadStream().on('end') 1 times

Solution: you should put points 3 4 5 into the `.on('end')` handler like

```
.on('end', () => {
  console.log(results);
  bulk_emp_data = results;
  console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
  console.log(bulk_emp_data.length);

  console.log('sample output');

  var data = {
    success: 1,
    msg: 'Successfully parsed the sample file.',
    data: bulk_emp_data.length
  };

  response.json(data);
});
```

Comment: seems that my lack of knowledge regarding file stream is really the problem here. Thanks!

Comment: Happens, fortunately the solution is not complex! Try the new implementation, if it works correctly, also marks the answer as accepted please :)